# Anyway to use PHPmyadmin with php 5.5 built in web server on Mac OS?

Tags: php, macos, phpmyadmin, webserver

Hi I am running a localserver using php's built in web server by executing the command "php -S localhost:8080" is there anyway to additionally run phpmyAdmin as well with this built in server (without having to use xamp)?

Comment: http://www.zyxware.com/articles/5139/how-to-run-phpmyadmin-without-apache-only-using-the-php-built-in-web-server

Comment: I believe this is for linux as it uses "sudo apt-get" however my question is regarding mac os x

Comment: Fair enough; with Homebrew, `brew install mysql`

Answer (score 1):

Original Answer: https://gist.github.com/iturgeon/0bf432de45a2f19aeb38e2bbae8a4567

Running phpMyAdmin localy on the built in php server

1. make sure you have php 5.3+: run php -v
2. Download phpmyadmin (github or main website)
3. In the root directory, copy config.sample.inc.php > config.inc.php
4. Edit config.inc.php, set $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] to the ip address of your mysql 5. server (probably localhost or 127.0.0.1)
5. In the root phpmyadmin directory run php -S localhost:8080
6. open in your browser: http://localhost:8080
7. log in by entering some valid credentials (a user you added or the root user)